# Is there any way to get image path from image view in android?

Tags: android, path, imageview

I have used imageview to capture & load images from gallery 
But now I need to send that images to server using path of an image.can anyone help me in getting filepath of that image from imageview.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First set imageview
imageview.buildDrawingCache();

//getBitmap from ImageView
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, imagePath, name, description);
```